# Mimic window load event in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I need to pull the width of images, which I can only do after the window load event.

Of course, this doesn't fire in jQuery Mobile, so I need an equivalent.

I have:

```
$(window).load(function(){
            var diff = $('div.canvas img.photo').get(1).width;
            console.log(diff);
        });
```

which obviously works fine when not loaded through AJAX, but I have cycled though the various events Jquery Mobile provides, and I can't get it to return the correct value.

```
$(document).live('pageshow', function(){
        var diff = $('div.canvas img.photo').get(1).width;
        console.log(diff);
    });
```

Essentially it needs to return the width of an image on a newly loaded page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

pageLoad Event.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html

Will need to wire it up though

Comment: You going to need to bind the event to a function. It is all in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: As I implied in my question, I have cycled though the events jQuery Mobile provides, using live AND bind methods. No Joy

Comment: bind to the element not the document as outlined in the first paragraph of the link I supplied. See bottom of page for example